# Restarting specific container of docker stack

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I started up set of docker containers by running `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.dev.yml mystack`. It started following container along with others:

```
$ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS             NAMES
de396c7aab0e   nodejs:myapp              "/bin/sh -c /entrypo…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute                     mystack_nodejs.1.4h03pnxae13ejqwdbsegstmib
```

There are 5 more containers which I did not listed. This container contains react app. One of other containers contain django app to which I have connected my vscode and started debug session. So I want to only restart this specific nodejs container.

I tried:

```
docker container stop mystack_nodejs.1.4h03pnxae13ejqwdbsegstmib
```

I also tried

```
docker container stop de396c7aab0e
```

But this container is still shown in the `docker container ls` output.

Is it not possible to restart only specific container of docker stack?

Answer (score 0):

In docker swarm, service restarts its corresponding container which is turned off for any reason. Thus, in my case also, the turned off container was restarting because the corresponding service was making it to restart.

I am able to restart specific container by running `docker service update --force <service-name>`.

You can find all `<service-names>`s by running `docker service ls`.